# How can I use an ID field which is dynamic when running JavascriptExecutor with getElementById

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am attempting to run a selenium script which will return the text displayed on the screen after a user input into a dynamic search field.

I am able to enter the text and see the results on screen but my Javascript to output the text does not work as the ID field I am using is dynamic.

I am trying to get the text to display in the Browser Console so I can use that in my Javascript. If I try by ID but use the dynamically assigned ID then I get the appropriate return, however, the next time the page refreshes that ID will no longer be valid.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    id="origin-29890" 
    name="origin" 
    class="ej-input origin ui-autocomplete-input" 
    required="" 
    aria-label="From Airport" 
    data-routesearch-placeholder="e.g. London Gatwick" 
    aria-describedby="route-search-origin-description" 
    aria-autocomplete="list" 
    aria-expanded="false" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    aria-owns="ui-id-1" 
    placeholder="e.g. London Gatwick" 
    aria-activedescendant="selected-autocomplete-item">
```

If I try to use getElementsByClassName instead then on running that in the browser console I don't get what I'm looking for;

`"f values() { [native code] }`

If the field was static then the following would work

```
String script = "return document.getElementById(\"origin\").value";
String text= (String) jse.executeScript(script);
System.out.println(text);
```

I'm looking for a way of either changing the return document line to use a dynamic id or showever make the script accept the Xpath so I can include a starts with tag

Comment: What about assigning the id to a global variable and use it inside getElementById() ?

Comment: Could you share your HTML as well?

Comment: Added the HTML as requested

Comment: Are to trying to send text to `From Airport` field and then extract the same text from the same field? What is your exact usecase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate the element using [XPath locator](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) like:

```
WebElement myInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='origin']"));
```

once done you can get its [`id` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp):

```
System.out.println(myInput.getAttribute("id"));
```

or if you want you can obtain the [`value` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) via [JavaScriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) like:

```
 System.out.println(driver.executeScript("return [0].value", myInput));
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I spent so long trying to work out how to make it so that the getElementById tag used only part of the ID tag in a sort of xpath starts-with manner and never thought to work out what the ID was before I got to that part and just add it in.

Comment: @StevenK Instead of xpath you can use `By.name("origin")` as well.

Comment: There's no point in getting the ID once you have the element. If you really need to click, etc. using JS, you can just pass in the element and click it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find it by name. Please try this:

```
String script = "return document.getElementsByName(\"origin\").value";
```